# SAS and Visual Studio Code Snippets

Tags: visual-studio-code, sas

I'm working with SAS Enterprise Guide for the first time, and it's in a highly secure remote environment. So far, I find that auto-complete when writing code is virtually nonexistent, even though I've ensured it is turned on in the settings. I can write the code in Visual Studio Code, which has a SAS extension and great contextual help, but it of course doesn't have the library, table and column names available to it. I've been reading up a bit on adding custom snippets for auto completion in VSC, and I'm wondering if it might be possible to feed it a json file with every library, table and column name. Does anyone know if that's possible?

Comment: Did you check with your sas server admin?   If you have a library assigned that gives you access to the data, I can't imagine why EG wouldn't be able to do auto-complete. You might want to talk with SAS support as well.

Comment: Maybe I don't know how to work it properly. In a proc sql statement, when I start typing the library, it works, and then when I type the dot and start typing the table name, that works too. But when I give it the alias "as a" then try to select column names by starting with a., commands come up in the auto-complete, but not column names.

Comment: That could be a limitation of EG autocomplete.  Definitely possible it doesn't know about sql aliases.

Comment: Tom, you could do this as an EG add-in. They are written in C# and simply need to follow certain interfaces. They work great and it is fairly easy to get the metadata. That said, it isn't a light project but it is very doable. If you know C#, you are looking at a few days to do it. See if Chris Hemendinger, SAS Community lead, has any existing add-ins that might work.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be very easy to give Visual Studio Code your own list of auto-complete options. Go to File menu->Preferences->Configure User Snippets. It will ask you to choose the language, then open a json file for you to edit. In my instance it was named sas.json.

You can add your own entries in this format:

```
{
  "my_term": {
    "prefix": "my_term",
    "body": ["my_term"]
}
```

As soon as you save the json file, the auto-complete is available to your code written in the selected language. The prefix can be different from the actual term if you wanted to use a different prompt.